# I can no longer edit or save my list's view, possibly due to a "phantom column."

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view

I've stumbled upon an issue with one of my SharePoint lists that is preventing me from editing the list's View, or saving the current view under a new name. This is the screen I get when I click on "edit view" from the view drop-down:
[image]
(Error reads: "Sorry, something went wrong// An unexpected error has occured.// Correlation ID: fa9e149f-90e7-9000-89f1-9d7048dbb1dc")

And this is the error I get when trying to save the current view under a new name:

[image]

(Error reads: "Column 'Listapprovaldateby_x005b_jobtitl0' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.")

At one point I had two "approval" columns in my list. One was titled "List Approval Date by [ job title 1 ]", and the other titled "List Approval Date by [ job title 2 ]". I then decided that two separate columns were not needed, so I deleted "List Approval Date by [ job title 2 ]" and renamed the first column to "List Approval Date by Both Job Titles."
After deleting one and renaming the other, this issue began occurring.

My guess is that I've somehow left a "phantom column" on this list but have no access to it, so SharePoint freaks out whenever it tries to look at a view. But I have no idea of how to clear out the phantom or how to save/edit the view otherwise.

(note: as far as i can tell, no other functions on the list or site have been affected apart from editing the view of this particular list. Also there is no evidence of the "phantom" column anywhere other than this error message.)

Any help or idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Would deleting the problem column be an option for you (deleting the column you renamed)?  You could also try deleting the view and create a new one.

Another suggestion is to attempt to edit the view via List Settings > scroll down to **Columns** - can you see your phantom column here?  What happens if you search for the column in Sharepoint Designer, can you see it there?

The 'url' for your renamed column will remain the same, even if you rename it.  If you tried to manually type in the name of the column (see my example below - based on the Created column):

https://YourSharepointSite.YourCompanyName.com/SiteCollection/_layouts/15/FldEditEx.aspx?List=YourListID(AlphaNumericCode&Field=**Created**

-> If you can exactly remember letter-for-letter your original column name, you can try to type it manually to see if it still exists.

If this doesn't work, then perhaps someone can suggest a powershell script which would scan your list and show all available columns (I lack the expertise I'm afraid).